# Sound problem in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, asus

my speakers have some problem I've tried several things on the internet but can't resolve the issue, sound appear and after few seconds disappears. also headphone is not working! this my laptop info:

```
inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: Benyamin Kernel: 5.8.0-38-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ZenBook UX334FLC_UX333FLC v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX334FLC v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: UX334FLC.303 date: 12/13/2019 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-38-generic
```

Comment: When dual-booting disabling Fast Startup in Windows is a must. In some cases hardware may not be correctly initialized in the other OS. Your answer seems to confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it happens because of my windows installation on the same machine along side of the ubuntu. Every time I switch between ubuntu and windows I face this problem. I found a strange way to solve this though: Shutdown the machine completely and start once again and boot the machine with ubuntu! problem solved!